# create view column name from other table rows and set value if column exists as value mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table: two tables; one contains options value and another contains options name.
option table something like the following :

```
| id.       | procedure                         | associated_disorder
|-----------|-----------------------------------|------------------------        
| 1         | Wound Stitching, Removal of pop   | Cleft Lip, Cleft Palate                 
| 2         | Nasal Packing, Wound Stitching    | Dementia, Cleft Lip
```

other table contains all the options:

```
| id.       | type                              | name
|-----------|-----------------------------------|------------------------        
| 1         | PROCEDURE                         | Wound Stitching                 
| 2         | PROCEDURE                         | Removal of pop
| 3         | ASSOCIATED_DISORDER               | Cleft Lip
| 4         | ASSOCIATED_DISORDER               | Dementia
```

I want the view to contain the columns:

```
| id. | procedure                      | associated_disorder    |Wound Stitching|Removal of pop|Nasal Packing
|-----|--------------------------------|------------------------|---------------|--------------|-------------
| 1   | Wound Stitching, Removal of pop| Cleft Lip, Cleft Palate| 1             | 1            | 0     
| 2   | Nasal Packing, Wound Stitching | Dementia, Cleft Lip    | 0             | 0            | 1
```

Comment: sorry, MySQL @ErgestBasha

Comment: no, it may be just a single value @ErgestBasha

Comment: By the way as far as I know I do not think this can be done with a view if the values are dynamic in the procedure column, you need a store procedure. Something like [MySQL query to dynamically convert rows to columns on the basis of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns) after converting comma separated string to rows

Comment: Does "wound stitching" apply to both "cleft lip" and "cleft palate"?

Comment: Cleft Lip, Cleft Palate, Dementia and Cleft Lip are types of ASSOCIATED_DISORDER. while Wound Stitching, Removal of pop, Nasal Packing and Wound Stitching are PROCEDURE types @RickJames

Comment: is there another way I can achieve the desired results? @ErgestBasha

Comment: The function `FIND_IN_SET()` may be part of the solution.

Comment: Will the `VIEW` have exactly 6 columns?  Or does it need to have as many columns as there are 'Procedures', in which case see the tag [pivot].

Comment: The "Procedure" list can be 200 options so the view should also have exact numbers of columns. @RickJames

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` can you please give an example query of how it can help me? @RickJames

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150325/discussion-between-umar-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will generate the third table:

```
SELECT
   t1.id, t1.procedure, t1.associated_disorder,
   FIND_IN_SET(t1.procedure, "Wound Stitching") > 0 AS "Wound Stitching",
   FIND_IN_SET(t1.procedure, "Removal of pop") > 0 AS "Removal of pop",
   ...
   FROM t1;
```

(Note that `expr > 0` will generate `1` or `0`, as needed.)

The big part of generating that query is in building the columns; something like this will generate the 200 options:

```
SELECT CONCAT(' FIND_IN_SET(t1,procedure, "',
              t2.associated_disorder,
              '") > 0 AS "',
              t2.associated_disorder,
              '",')
    FROM t2;
```

Note: there will be an extra comma at the end that could be manually removed.